# Stanford CoreNLP, spring web service, Netbeans 8.0.1 and Out of memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run a web service that will provide interface for parsing sentences into RDF triples. So far I was able to run simple spring app with one controller and displaying magic "Hello World".

I run into a problem when I add CoreNLP.

```
SEVERE:   Adding annotator tokenize
SEVERE:   Adding annotator ssplit
SEVERE:   Adding annotator pos
SEVERE:   Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
SEVERE:   ...
SEVERE:   done [1,2 sec].
SEVERE:   Adding annotator lemma
SEVERE:   Adding annotator ner
SEVERE:   Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
SEVERE:   ...
SEVERE:   done [4,0 sec].
SEVERE:   Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
SEVERE:   ...
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

As it is mentioned here http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml [num. 6] I tried to set VM option **-Xmx4g** like this: **right click on project -> Properties -> Configurations -> Add**. And I created new configuration **run.args.extra=-Xmx4g**

**EDIT 1**

So I run jsp comman and I have no idea what it means. I got this:

```
1268 Jps -Denv.class.path=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip -Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17 -Xms8m
7496  -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense -client -Xss2m -Xms32
m -XX:PermSize=32m -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -Dsun.zi
p.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17 -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.
1\platform -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\majernikm\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1 -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\majernikm\AppData\Roaming\NetBea
ns -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\majernikm\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\var\log\heapdump.hprof -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetO
nMinimize=true -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\nb;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\ergonomics;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\ide;C:\Pr
ogram Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\extide;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\apisupport;C:\Program Files
6596 Program
8612 NetworkServerControl -Dderby.system.home=C:\Users\majernikm\.netbeans-derby
6900 ASMain -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -Djavax.mana
gement.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\gl
assfish-4.1\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish/lib/endorsed -Djava.security.policy=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\gla
ssfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.co
nf -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as -Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1
/config/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks -Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program
 Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1/l
```

**EDIT 2 - ANSWER**

In **my case** the solution was to change Glassfish to **Tomcat** and it started working :). Thanks a lot for everybody that helped.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Michal

Comment: Use `jps` and `jstat` (or `jconsole`) utilities to check if that settings is actually used when your process/application is run. Maybe it needs to be applied in a different way.
You can also tweak Ant settings to produce verbose output to see the command used to run the application and possible check how some of the properties are set.

Comment: I edited question with result of jsp command

Answer (score 0):

You are using Stanford Core NLP which is taking too much heap size mainly NER. Just restart the netbean and give the heap memory in multiple of 1024.I used that code in -Xmx4096M heap size and worked.

like  `-Xmx4096M or -Xmx5120M`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for quick answer. I have changed run.args.extra=-Xmx4g to run.args.extra=-Xmx4096M, saved, restarted Netbeans, selected my configuration from dropdown list in a tool bar, run and got same error. Any other sugestions?

Comment: neither -Xmx8192M works. So maybe there is a problem somewhere else. Am I configurating it corectly? I mean with this adding and using configuration?

Comment: It means in your Core NLP program, there is no problem. Problem is in your servlet() or any where else. for just testing. you just extract POS only. Is pos extraction is working or not.

 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos");
if it is working then add ner or any other property

Comment: This time it was ok. Quite fast. I just need to review the result now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to change Glassfish to **Tomcat** and it started working :). Thanks a lot for everybody that helped